# Does Lucio's aura look like a sphere or a cylinder?

Tags: overwatch

[image]

How does Lucios aura look like?

Answer (score 2):

All abilities I see (from [here](https://overwatch.fandom.com/wiki/L%C3%BAcio#Abilities)) have a radius of 8/12/30 meter. This results in a sphere-like volume in which the effect takes place, not in an infinite high cylinder.

I read from a comment on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Overwatch/comments/684wp3/is_lucios_heal_a_cylider_or_a_sphere/) that the animation seems like a cylinder. Probably there the confusion is coming from, and other comments verify this sphere-like behavior.

> It's a sphere even though the aura indicates that it goes vertically like a cylinder.